# Why is $\vec V_{ab}=\sqrt3 \vec V_{an}(0.866+0.5j)$?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Here is the equilateral triangle,and the book said $\vec V_{ab}=\sqrt3 \vec V_{an}(0.866+0.5j)$,and $n$ point is the center of the triangle.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Presumably the number in brackets is meant to give the (approximate) value of the answer. However the vector arrows are a mistake, and we don't know where the point $n$ is to work out whether the magnitudes are correct.

Comment: @Peter n point is the center of the triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the vector arrows and only consider magnitudes. Add a point $m$ at the mid-point of $bc$, noting that $a, n, m$ are collinear. Suppose the length ab is $1$. Trigonometry shows us that the lengths of $am$ and $mb$ are $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ respectively; looking up the values to 3 figure accuracy gives the answer in brackets.

The centroid and other centre points of an equilateral triangle coincide at a point $\frac{2}{3}$ of the way from $a$ to $m$, so $an = \frac{2}{3}. am = \frac{2}{3}.\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.ab=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}ab$. The first part of the statement follows.